# Ll вместо ls

Tags: ubuntu, linux

как сделать чтобы список файлов выводился в формате ls -l. до обновления работала команда ll. сейчас только ls.
ubuntu 12.04
спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
```

и будет работать ll

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю к предыдущему ответившему. Если оболочка bash (а это скорее всего именно так), то чтоб не вводить алиасы каждый раз, их можно добавить в ~/.bashrc
Этот файл выполняется при каждом логине

Answer (score 2):

Файл в котором описана ll в Убунту лежит в /etc/skel/.bashrc

При создании нового пользователя он содержимое каталога skel копируется в домашний. Скорее всего Вы удалили случайно ~/.bashrc, и поэтому алиасы не работали.